# Various JS templates; Why two {?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I'm puzzled by this notation that did spread a lot after the first templating engine using it became successful. The notation is {{bla}}

Does anyone know the practical reason for having two sets of {}? I think it reads very poorly; The deprecated JQuery one made more sense ( ${bla} )

Comment: Probably because it's not very likely to interfere with normal text, minimizing the need to escape stuff..

Comment: I would have thought one doesn't need to have a { or } often in his html markup. I would rather have to escape very rarely that getting a weird notation at all times ?

Comment: The `{` and `}` is used all the time in HTML (CSS, embedded Javascript, etc) as well as text on the actual page.  I'd rather have something easy to remember such as the double-curly-brace than a combination of characters.  Can anyone remember off the top of their head how to write a CDATA?  I always have to Google it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it's not an often used combination of characters.

Template parsing is all about regular expressions and then turning the text into tokens, and then compiling those tokens into another language (like HTML).

Since we don't want to catch common characters in our regular expressions, we need to use those that aren't common combos of characters.

it's the same reason PHP uses `<?php ?>` and ASP uses `<% %>`.

Like in [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org), the lexer looks for `{{ }}` and `{% %}` to find Twig commands.  If I had to use `{ }`, every time I had that anywhere in the template (not just HTML markup), I'd have to escape it.  And since the point of a template language is ease of use, The language needs to make its "tokens" as distinguishable as possible.

Comment: I should add that there's nothing new about `{{ }}` and it wasn't invented by handlebars.js.

Comment: I accepted the answer because it's likely to be the intent of those templating engines' authors. However, I'm still not convinced it's the most readable notation :)

Answer (score -1):

How come Distal works without needing any escape characters like {{}}? http://code.google.com/p/distal

Comment: Different design maybe? This is off topic, -1. By the size of the project, I am guessing self-promotion.

Comment: Plus, it's not a true template language (by what I see on the front page of the project).  It looks like it uses the DOM and HTML attributes.

Comment: @Louis: OP didn't mention any specific templating engine so all templating engines are fair game. Not off topic. -- It is a templating language. See TAL spec here http://wiki.zope.org/ZPT/TAL

Comment: @KernelJames: I know it's nitpicking, but it's not really a "language".  It's a nifty tool, to be sure, but there's no lexing, parsing, tokenizing, or compiling done.